# Inventory management - find employees with two OR more particular devices

Tags: excel

I am managing the inventory of stock for an IT company.

Recently we've had to dole out lots of new iPhones as the old iPhones assigned to employees were incompatible with a particular piece of software.

With most employees working from home and IT staff being split into several different offices it can be a little difficult to co-ordinate things and make sure that the staff member who received a replacement iPhone actually sent back the original one!

It would be great to have an easy means of check for staff who have **two** (or possibly more) iPhones (any type) so that I can contact them and ask them to return the old device.

I can export the data from the SQL-based equipment database to Excel and analyse it but I don't have the experience to make things more automatic (and build a report).

Here is an example of the database (shown as an Excel file).

[image]

In this example case, John Murphy, has got two iPhones. He only needs one of them. Items with the "Employee_Name" set to "IT Service" and have the status set to 'With helpdesk' are in order and do not need to be included in the final report.

'Tammy Top' has only one iPhone and therefore mustn't appear in the report.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE...

I've played around with Pivot Tables a little... it may be a start. Perhaps if someone is more experienced they could suggest a better way of setting up the values for the pivot table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure, that there are better solutions.

But at the moment, I can offer you the following:

- `E2`: `=IF(AND(A2="IT Service", D2="With helpdesk"),0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$D$2:$D2,D2))`
- `G2`: `=FILTER(A2:D6,(E2:E6>1),"")`

In column `E` I used a `COUNTIFS` formula to check how often an *Employee_Name* has occured until now. I wrapped it in an `IF` statement, that checks whether the combination of "IT Service" and "With helpdesk" occured. In that case, it would override the counter with 0.

In column `G` I used a `FILTER` formula to provide the relevant rows (A to D) of the source area in case the counter is higher than 1.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I've found a way of weeding out employees who only appears once by using pivot tables. Drag "EmployeeName" to Row Labels and also drag "EmployeeName" to Values. One can then do an ascending sort and hide those who only make one appearance as well as 'IT Service'. Only those with two (or more) iPhones remain. Your formula definitely has fewer 'musical chairs'! A good thing. I will try it on the full data set when I get to the office tmrw. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the data is in SQL Server, just query the database instead of mucking around in Excel.

Something like:

```
SELECT Employee_Name FROM <table> GROUP BY Employee_Name WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 AND Employee_Name <> 'IT Service'
```

Should get a list of Employees with more than one phone. To get the full list something like:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE Employee_Name IN (
    SELECT Employee_Name FROM <table> GROUP BY Employee_Name WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 AND Employee_Name <> 'IT Service')
```

should get you the list you want.

being the name of the table/view/SP that is generating the data you are importing into Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am only a "grunt" in terms of the IT foodchain and don't have access to the SQL dataset itself (but rather the HTML front-end). For the time being I have to do with the 'Export to Excel' function it offers.